# Transform XMI to XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xmi

I have a question regarding the Transformation of my data model (XMI) to a XML representation with XSLT. The XMI Looks like this (snippet):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.1" xmlns:uml="http://schema.omg.org/spec/UML/2.1" xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1" xmlns:thecustomprofile="http://www.sparxsystems.com/profiles/thecustomprofile/1.0" xmlns:EAUML="http://www.sparxsystems.com/profiles/EAUML/1.0">
<xmi:Documentation exporter="Enterprise Architect" exporterVersion="6.5"/>
<uml:Model xmi:type="uml:Model" name="EA_Model" visibility="public">
    <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Package" xmi:id="EAPK_F3388CFE_57A7_4d84_8866_3FB3AADE565A" name="Data Model - SQLServer2012" visibility="public">
        <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Artifact" xmi:id="EAID_B62341D4_41C6_4c83_A60A_4CA65C2E185E" name="«Database» SQLServer2012" visibility="public"/>
        <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Package" xmi:id="EAPK_BA7676C5_40BC_4bd9_A0F5_F6B15E534E8E" name="Logical Model" visibility="public">
            <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="EAID_2DC36189_CCFB_40bf_A1CB_CD4FB08FE8B5" name="TABLENAME" visibility="public">
                <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="EAID_9BBF5184_37F8_4729_9DC1_7ED3B4D8FC98" name="ATTRIBUTE_1" visibility="public" isStatic="false" isReadOnly="false" isDerived="false" isOrdered="true" isUnique="false" isDerivedUnion="false">
                    <lowerValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="EAID_LI000001_37F8_4729_9DC1_7ED3B4D8FC98" value="1"/>
                    <upperValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="EAID_LI000002_37F8_4729_9DC1_7ED3B4D8FC98" value="1"/>
                    <type xmi:idref="EASQL_Server_2012_nvarchar"/>
                </ownedAttribute>
                <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="EAID_BC1F93D0_A7F4_474c_A27E_26D3ABCCFB7B" name="ATTRIBUTE_2" visibility="public" isStatic="false" isReadOnly="false" isDerived="false" isOrdered="false" isUnique="true" isDerivedUnion="false">
                    <lowerValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="EAID_LI000003_A7F4_474c_A27E_26D3ABCCFB7B" value="1"/>
                    <upperValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="EAID_LI000004_A7F4_474c_A27E_26D3ABCCFB7B" value="1"/>
                    <type xmi:idref="EASQL_Server_2012_nvarchar"/>
                </ownedAttribute>
```

So now I would like to write a XSL-File which enables me to extract the tablename:

```
-> packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class"
```

and the attributes

```
-> ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property"
```

and the datatypes for each Attribute.

Finally I Need to transform These informations into an XML-representation like this:

```
<Segment Name="TABLENAME">
  <Elements>
    <Element Name="ATTRIBUTE_1" Type="System.blabla">
    </Element>
    <Element Name="ATTRIBUTE_2" Type="System.blabla">
    </Element>
  </Elements>
</Segment>
```

Can someone give my some hint/sample on how to achieve this?

Any help is very appreciated.

Cheers
Sandro

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: Can you show the XSLT with an explanation to where you are stuck with it? And please, show minimal working examples, your XML is not complete. Take a minute to read [mcve], the [faq] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

This is only a guess since the example is incomplete.
This is going about it (a bit the hard way) by specifying everything in TEXT, but it worked for me.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!-- ================================================== -->
  <xsl:stylesheet  version="2.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:uml="http://schema.omg.org/spec/UML/2.1" 
     xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1" 
     xmlns:thecustomprofile="http://www.sparxsystems.com/profiles/thecustomprofile/1.0" 
     >
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
     <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>

     <xsl:template match="xmi:XMI">

        <xsl:for-each select="uml:Model/packagedElement/packagedElement/packagedElement[@xmi:type='uml:Class']">
           <xsl:value-of select="'&lt;Segment Name=&quot;'"/>
           <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
           <xsl:value-of select="'&quot;&gt;'"/>
           <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>

           <xsl:value-of select="'&lt;Elements&gt;'"/>
           <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>

           <xsl:for-each select="ownedAttribute[@xmi:type='uml:Property']">
              <xsl:value-of select="'&lt;Element Name=&quot;'"/>
              <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
              <xsl:value-of select="'&quot;&gt;'"/>
              <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>

              <xsl:value-of select="'&lt;/Element&gt;'"/>
              <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
           </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:value-of select="'&lt;/Elements&gt;'"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="'&lt;/Segment&gt;'"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>

     </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: My Problem is the following.

In my case the tablename is located in the xmi Attribute "packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" in the "name" field and the attributes of the table in "ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" also in the Name field.

So what's not clear to me is how do I define in XSL that the values in these xmi attributes are translated into the XML representation shown in the above example.

My XML is not complete, I know sry. This is because the entries are repeated for every table (class) and the contained attributes (property)

I try the above solution and give Feedback :)

Comment: FWIW (and compliments to understanding the OP's requirements!), if you use `xsl:value-of` with literals, you can just as well use `xsl:text` and save yourself some typing and improve readability. I.e. `<xsl:value-of select="'&lt;Segment Name=&quot;'"/>` then becomes `<xsl:text>&lt;Segment Name="</xsl:text>`.

Comment: I did know about <text>, but didn't know I could use a (bare) " within that space!  that was new to me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you are only really interested in a couple of elements in your XML, you can take advantage of XSLT's [built-in templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule), which effectively skip over all elements and only outputs text nodes (of which there are only whitespace ones in your XML). This means you only need to write two templates; one for each of the elements you do want to process.

So, for the `packagedElement` with a type of `uml:Class`, you are creating a `Segment` element, so the template would look like this

```
<xsl:template match="packagedElement[@xmi:type='uml:Class']">
    <Segment Name="{@name}">
        <Elements>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </Elements>
    </Segment>            
</xsl:template>
```

Note the use of [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) in creating the `Name` attribute. The curly braces means the expression has to be evaluated, not output literally.

Similarly for the `ownedAttribute` element.

```
<xsl:template match="ownedAttribute[@xmi:type='uml:Property']">
    <Element Name="{@name}" Type="System.blabla">
    </Element>         
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="packagedElement[@xmi:type='uml:Class']">
        <Segment Name="{@name}">
            <Elements>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </Elements>
        </Segment>            
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ownedAttribute[@xmi:type='uml:Property']">
        <Element Name="{@name}" Type="System.blabla">
        </Element>         
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also note how the there is a definition for the namespaces prefix `xmi`, which the namespace URI matching the one in the input XML.